# How to write LEFT OUTER JOIN on the same table in jOOQ?

Tags: mysql, sql, jooq

how to write following SQL using jOOQ?

```
SELECT *
FROM food_db_schema.tblCategory AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN food_db_schema.tblCategory AS t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t2.parent_id IS NULL
AND t1.heartbeat = "ALIVE";
```

database is mySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe

```
SELECT *
FROM food_db_schema.tblCategory AS t1
WHERE t1.category_id IS NULL
AND t1.heartbeat = "ALIVE";
```

, but are you sure `t2.parent_id` is both supposed to be NULL and equal to `t1.category_id`?

**EDIT:**

Then something like

```
Table<TblCategoryRecord> t1 = TBLCATEGORY.as("t1");
Table<TblCategoryRecord> t2 = TBLCATEGORY.as("t2");

Field<Integer> t1CategoryId = t1.getField(TblCategory.CATEGORY_ID);
Field<String> t1Heartbeat = t1.getField(TblCategory.HEARTBEAT);
Field<Integer> t2ParentId = t2.getField(TblCategory.PARENT_ID);

Record record = create.select().from(t1)
      .leftOuterJoin(t2).on(t1CategoryId.equal(t2ParentId))
      .where(t2ParentId.isNull())
      .and(t1Heartbeat.equal("ALIVE"));
```

depending on what the generated classes, properties and meta-model objects are called.

Comment: The select works as I need. It selects parents without children in a tree structure. I am asking for help to map it in jOOQ. Of course I can implement it in a raw JDBC.

Comment: The `create.selectFrom(...)` syntax doesn't allow for joins. You could re-write that to `.select().from(t1)`, though

Comment: @Lukas: Thanks. I'm not on my development computer, so I hadn't tested it.

Answer (score 12):

[flesk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197595/521799) depicts nicely how this can be done with jOOQ 1.x. A self-join using aliasing is more or less equivalent to a regular join using aliasing as described in the manual:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/

In the upcoming version 2.0, aliasing will be made less verbose and more type-safe. Hence flesk's solution could be simplified as such:

```java
// Type-safe table aliasing:
TblCategory t1 = TBLCATEGORY.as("t1");
TblCategory t2 = TBLCATEGORY.as("t2");

Record record = create.select()
                      .from(t1)
                       // t1 and t2 give access to aliased fields:
                      .leftOuterJoin(t2).on(t1.CATEGORY_ID.equal(t2.PARENT_ID))
                      .where(t2.PARENT_ID.isNull())
                      .and(t1.HEARTBEAT.equal("ALIVE"));
```

I have also described a more complex example for a self-join here:

http://blog.jooq.org/jooq-meta-a-hard-core-sql-proof-of-concept/

Comment: That looks sweet. I'm used to Hibernate criteria, but JOOQ feels a lot more intuitive when you've been writing SQL statements your entire adult life.